# Unexpected add action function in WP plugin

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development

I'm trying to build out a plugin from a tutorial that will access my google calendar.  So far I'm stuck on just trying to register the widget.  Here is a link to the tutorial:

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-google-calendar-plugin-for-wordpress--cms-32710

I keep running into the problem of the 'add_action' function at the bottom of the script.  I keep getting an error of 'syntax error, unexpected 'add_action'.  I'm not even sure I'm building this correctly.

```php
<?php

/** 
 * Plugin Name: My gCal Plugin
 * Description: Displays upcoming events from Google calender
 * version: 1.0.0
 * 
 * 
 */


class My_gCal_Widget extends WP_Widget
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(
            'my_gcal_widget',
            'My_gCal_Widget',
            array(
                'classname' => 'my-gcal-widget',
                'description' => 'Shows events from a calendar'
            )
        );
    }

    public function widget($args, $instance)
    {
    }
}

add_action('widgets_init', function () {
    register_widget('My_gCal_Widget');
});
```

Comment: your code has no indentation, which conceals lots of possible problems, please indent your code correctly, it will make the issue more obvious and help people trying to answer your question. Use the `Edit` link under the tags to update your question

Comment: which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @TomJNowell 7.3.5

Comment: No syntax issues were found via some checker tools, can you delete the contents of your file then replace them with the code in your question? I do not believe the cause of the problem has survived the transition from your file to your question. Also please update the question with the full error message shown in the PHP error log or in the WP Admin area on activation

Comment: otherwise the only way I can see this PHP syntax error being a thing is if you try to load the file directly in the browser. It's possible VS Code has not been configured and isn't aware of WordPress PHP functions and you should ignore it. Unless your code generates a syntax error when it runs there is no syntax error. As for why your widget doesn't show, did you activate the plugin? And did you follow the rest of the tutorial? Your widget does not have any form or update functions

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear in the tutorial, but the `add_action()` call should be *outside* the class.

```
class My_gCal_Widget extends WP_Widget {
    public function __construct() {
        parent:: __construct(
            'my_gcal_widget',
            'My_gCal_Widget',
            array(
                'classname' => 'my-gcal-widget',
                'description' => 'Shows events from a calendar'
            )
        );
    }

    public function widget($args, $instance) { }

}

add_action('widgets_init', function() {
    register_widget('My_gCal_Widget');
});
```

Comment: That's what I thought too, but same error occurs.

Comment: @RRhodes where is this file and how is it being loaded? Are you trying to load it directly in the browser bypassing WordPress?

Comment: @TomJNowell The file is my plugins folder.  I'm fairly new to this, so I'm just following the tutorial.  The author didn't mention how to load the file.

Comment: You activate it like any other WordPress plugin: go to your WordPress admin pages (usually at `example.com/wp-admin`) and select **Plugins**. Find the **My GCal Plugin** plugin and click **Activate**.

Comment: @PatJ Yep, I did that part already

Comment: it's not clear what's happening, where are you seeing this error message? Also is your code in your question complete? There's no plugin header, and there's no indentation. Pat J is correct in their answer but it's clear that there is more to this than we've been told. I'd also note that for a first time tutorial you picked a tutorial that uses some rather advanced concepts with a lot of steps

Comment: @TomJNowell Ok, so I just edited my initial post and added everything that's in my php file.

Comment: @TomJNowell I should add that I'm seeing the error in my code editor (VSCode).  Also, I'm not seeing the widget in the WP admin under Appearance, where the widgets would usually appear.